# Are there no error logs for MySQL on Plesk server (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb, plesk, error-logging

I have installed a Plesk server with version 18.0.57 on an Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I am looking for the error logs for MySQL accesses or MariaDB accesses. But I can't find them via SSH.

Where could they be? They are not available under var/log/mysql, for example.

Greetings.